# Why does the Ethernet layer address have 48 bits?

Tags: internet-explorer, ip, ethernet

I know that general Internet packets addressing is 32 bits. But why the Ethernet layer has 48 bits address? Are the Ethernet layer and Ethernet frame the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no single "Ethernet layer". Ethernet defines a number of [physical layer variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_physical_layer) (L1) and uses a common data link layer (L2) across those. Many features of the data link layer are shared with several other IEEE protocols. The data link layer has many options but the core is common for all Ethernet networks.

For addressing, the data link layer uses EUI-48 addresses that are also shared with other protocols (such as Wi-Fi or Bluetooth). These EUI-48 addresses consist of two parts: 24 bits OUI - a vendor-specific prefix allocated be IEEE - and a 24-bit device-specific number.

The 48-bit size is a trade-off between keeping overhead down and providing sufficient address space to supply all potential vendors with. There are many vendors using multiple OUIs due to the volume of their production. Today there are also many virtual addresses in use (for virtual machines and interfaces), so a MAC address may not be as unique as it was originally defined.

Therefore, IEEE promotes the use of EUI-64 addresses for new protocols, expanding the address space by 65,536. EUI-64 addresses are already in use with IPv6, Firewire and ZigBee.

Why don't EUI-48 and IPv4 or IPv6 use the same address space? Simply put, they were developed completely independently and are tasked differently. IP has a logical, centrally organized address structure, enabling routing across a global network. Ethernet uses "unique physical" addresses that can be combined randomly but only work locally. In combination they make networks flexible and manageable.